Rebuilding master database drops all other db's
On SQL Server, We have a need to rebuild the master database on certain client systems as some of them have an incorrect collation on their master db which cause errors on joins with temp tables (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS).
The microsoft documentation specifies this command to rebuild the system db's:
setup /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /SAPWD=MyStrongpassword /SQLCOLLATION=Latin1_General_CI_AS

This does work, however after reconnection, all the user created db's have vanished! The mdf files are still there but it's not possible to reattach them. And anyway reattaching is not an option as the rebuild would be part of a script. Has anyone encountered this problem before and know of a solution?

It doesn't "drop" them, per say, the database file still exist, however, the instance no longer has them attached. This is expected behaviour, as the details of what databases are attached to the instance is stored in the master database; if you recreate that database ("reset it to factory defaults"), it contains no details of any user databases any more.

"The mdf files are still there but it's not possible to reattach them" yes, it is possible. If you've attempted to reattach them, and failed, that is what you should be asking about.

ohh, ok I understand. So creating a backup of those user settings on master and then restoring them will resolve the problem?

What do you mean by "creating a backup and then restoring"? As in backing up the master database and RESTOREing it? That would put you back where you were, with master in the collation you didn't want.

If this is your system, another approach is not to explicitly create temp tables but create them with SELECT ... INTO #temp FROM ... WHERE 1=0. Any string columns created this way will have the collation of the source tables. ie You will not have to worry about the server collation.

If you do not like SELECT ... INTO, and you are sure all you string columns have the same collation as you database, then you could just make sure all strings in temp tables are created with COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT.

I'm highly confused what your question is: if you rebuild master then by definition you lose everything in it, including the list of attached databases (you should be able to reattach), all logins, server-level roles and permissions, TDE certificates and DMKs, any other stored procedures etc you may have created there. It's completely fresh like a new installation. What else did you expect?

Yes. Changing the instance collation on customer machines seems like a very bad idea. The OP's code should always somehow define the collation of string columns for temp tables. Our test VMs are always built with a really obscure server collation to ensure there are no collation problems with temp tables.

I guess I didn't really understand what the master db is for and didn't realise it disconnects all user db's if you rebuild it. (I'm new at the company with a non sql background) I don't think there is a way around the problem other than setting 'collate default' on every string variable in temp tables.(which we are currently doing)
